# How to translate function names in the Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

When using list_display as described under http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display you can not only display fields but custom callables as well:

```
def colored_name(self):
    return '<span style="color: #%s;">%s %s</span>' % (self.color_code, self.first_name, self.last_name)
colored_name.allow_tags = True
```

And then use it like this:

```
list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'colored_name')
```

Since first_name and last_name are normal fields we can just translate them like that:

```
first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'))
last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'))
```

So the question is:

How can I translate the name of my function? Where do I put my _('colored name')?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The example on the page that you linked to shows that the callable can have an attribute `short_description`, which is the string used as the title of the column. I haven't checked, but I strongly suspect that if you set that to a translatable string then it will work.

```
def colored_name(self):
    return '<span style="color: #%s;">%s %s</span>' % (self.color_code, self.first_name, self.last_name)
colored_name.allow_tags = True
colored_name.short_description = _("Colored Name")
```

Comment: It was so obvious and I completely skipped that somehow. Thank you so much - that works like a charm.

Answer (score -3):

it's a function (a "callable") so the correct syntax should be

```
list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', colored_name)
```

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I just checked it - the correct syntax is 'colored_name' even though it's a callable. It doesn't work without the ''.